# Connection closed by ::1 error in cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I am trying to do ssh connection using cygwin. I have followed instructions given [here](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html). When I fire `ssh localhost` command I get `Connection closed by ::1` error. As I am newbie to unix and cygwin, I am not able to figure out what has gone wrong. Please can anyone tell me why this error comes and how to resolve it?

My cygwin shell looks as follows :

```
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/Shekhar/.ssh/id_rsa):
/home/Shekhar/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/Shekhar/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/Shekhar/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
85:69:77:cc:fd:21:8a:ce:fe:46:41:ee:c8:e7:3d:7b Shekhar@Shekhar-PC
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|         o + .   |
|        + = +... |
|       . o.+. ...|
|        S.o..   .|
|        oo +     |
|         o+ .    |
|        .  o o E |
|         .o. .+  |
+-----------------+

Shekhar@Shekhar-PC ~
$ cd ~/.ssh/

Shekhar@Shekhar-PC ~/.ssh
$ ls -l
total 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 Shekhar None 1200 Jun 16 19:49 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 Shekhar None 1675 Jun 20 08:55 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 Shekhar None  400 Jun 20 08:55 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 Shekhar None  171 Jun  6 23:28 known_hosts

Shekhar@Shekhar-PC ~/.ssh
$ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys

Shekhar@Shekhar-PC ~/.ssh
$ ssh localhost
Connection closed by ::1
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an SSH server listening on `::1`? Does it work if you try `ssh 127.0.0.1`? (maybe it's only listening on your IPv4 interface, or maybe it's not listening at all, or maybe a personal firewall is blocking it?)

Comment: How to check whether SSH server is listening or not? I have started cygwin ssh service through control panel > admin tools > services

Comment: @Mike, I tried `ssh 127.0.0.1` but getting same error. `connection closed by 127.0.0.1`

Comment: One way to test is to `telnet` to the SSH port and see if it's open. For example, `telnet localhost 22` on my Linux system connects and then prints `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7`. I'm guessing you wouldn't even get that far, which means there is likely a problem with either the SSH service or there is a firewall interfering.

Comment: @Mike, my problem is solved. I just removed cygwin and re-installed it and somehow its working properly now.

Comment: Mike, could you see this please -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824845/unable-to-ssh-to-localhost-on-cygwin

Answer (score -4, accepted):

My problem is solved. I just removed cygwin and re-installed it and somehow its working properly now.

Comment: can anyone explain reason for downvoting?

Comment: Because reinstalling OS on a minor issue is not a good advice

Comment: Please read answer carefully before down voting. I reinstalled Cygwin, I didn't reinstalled OS.

Comment: Yeah but you reinstalled cygwin. It is not a very good advice. I used OS just to give an example.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this same issue. The problem for me at least, was the creation of the cyg_server user using the ssh-host-config. It was created without a home directory and with it's shell set to /bin/false. So, I altered the /etc/passwd file for the cyg_server user to reflect /home/cyg_server (changed from /var/empty) and /bin/false to /bin/bash and created the home directory for the user. Tried to reconnect using the cyg_server user and voila.

in short:

```
mkdir /home/cyg_server
vim /etc/passwd
cyg_server:...(bunch of stuff)...:/var/empty:/bin/false
```

to

```
cyg_server:...(bunch of stuff)...:/home/cyg_server:/bin/bash
```

Presumably cygwin has a usermod command or synonym that would do this a little safer. But I was impatient and this is what I did. If anyone follows this please note to be extremely careful when editing the /etc/passwd file.

Comment: +1. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I had to do these to fix Op's problem: chown <USERNAME> /var/log/sshd.log
chown -R <USERNAME> /var/empty
chown <USERNAME> /etc/ssh*
chmod 755 /var/empty
chmod 644 /var/log/sshd.log

Comment: I found the ownership of /var/empty correctly set to cyg_server:Root. So I didn't change the home directory of cyg_server. Instead I changed only the shell from /bin/false to /bin/bash and it worked perfectly. Another thing is that users should ensure that cygwin batch file is run with administrator privileges. Many thanks.

Comment: I followed the suggestions and logged in using cyg_server and it worked like a charm ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Just in case other find the same problem. Since you selected the cyg_server as user name while configuring ssh try to connect as using "ssh cyg_server@localhost" command rather than the default "ssh localhost". The password can be same as what you provided while configuring

Answer (score 2):

Putting this here in case someone runs into this later. I had the same problem and reinstalling cygwin solved it... until I rebooted. Then I got the same error again. I now resolved the problem for the second time: instead of using the account name "cyg_server" that cygwin suggests to me when running ssh-host-config, I entered the name of my normal admin account on windows. Seems to be working so far.